# Syntax / Logical checker In Javascript?

Tags: javascript, error-handling, typechecking, syntax-checking

I'm building a solution for a client which allows them to create very basic code,
now i've done some basic syntax validation but I'm stuck at variable verification.

I know JSLint does this using Javascript and i was wondering if anyone knew of a good way to do this.

So for example say the user wrote the code

```
moose = "barry"
base = 0
if(moose == "barry"){base += 100}
```

Then i'm trying to find a way to clarify that the "if" expression is in the correct syntax, if the variable moose has been initialized etc etc 
but I want to do this without scanning character by character, 
the code is a mini language built just for this application so is very very basic and doesn't need to manage memory or anything like that.

I had thought about splitting first by Carriage Return and then by Space but there is nothing to say the user won't write something like `moose="barry"` or `if(moose=="barry")`
and there is nothing to say the user won't keep the result of a condition inline.

Obviously compilers and interpreters do this on a much more extensive scale but i'm not sure if they do do it character by character and if they do how have they optimized?

(Other option is I could send it back to PHP to process which would then releave the browser of responsibility)

Any suggestions?

Thanks

The use case is limited, the syntax will never be extended in this case, the language is a simple scripted language to enable the client to create a unique cost based on their users input the end result will be processed by PHP regardless to ensure the calculation can't be adjusted by the end user and to ensure there is some consistency.

So for example, say there is a base cost of £1.00
and there is a field on the form called "Additional Cost", the language will allow them manipulate the base cost relative to the "additional cost" field.

So

```
base = 1;
if(additional > 100 && additional < 150){base += 50}
elseif(additional == 150){base *= 150}
else{base += additional;}
```

This is a basic example of how the language would be used.

---

Thank you for all your answers, 
I've investigated a parser and creating one would be far more complex than is required
having run several tests with 1000's of lines of code and found that character by character it only takes a few seconds to process even on a single core P4 with 512mb of memory (which is far less than the customer uses)

I've decided to build a PHP based syntax checker which will check the information and convert the variables etc into valid PHP code whilst it's checking it (so that it's ready to be called later without recompilation) using this instead of javascript this seems more appropriate and will allow for more complex code to arise without hindering the validation process

It's only taken an hour and I have code which is able to check the validity of an if statement and isn't confused by nested if's, spaces or odd expressions, there is very little left to be checked whereas a parser and full blown scripting language would have taken a lot longer

You've all given me a lot to think about and i've rated relevant answers thank you

Comment: "it is very very basic" - this is vague. please describe in detail how basic or complex this "language" is.

Comment: Basic mathmetical operations (+,-,*,/),
Basic conditional statement (if, elseif,else)
Variables are only going to store Integer, Float or String
No Loops
No Returns
No Functions
No Classes
As I said very very simple the idea of the language is to take a starting value and allow the user to manipulate it based on field values they've created in an online builder

Comment: You say just basic mathematical operations, but your example has variable assignment which is more than mathematical operations. In addition, your mini-language has if and else statements, equality operators, advanced `+=` operator.

Comment: You should probably write a mini-spec of all the possible grammar combinations and expression combinations.

Comment: I pressed enter before finishing what i was writing please re-read and it will explain what it will handle although knowing this information is still irrelevant, 
the question was relating to how other platforms do it or if there is an optimized way of doing it regardless of the language the process is going to be similar.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you **really** want to do this — and by that I mean if you really want your software to work properly and predictably, without a bunch of weird "don't do this" special cases — you're going to have to write a real parser for your language. Once you have that, you can transform any program in your language into a data structure. With that data structure you'll be able to conduct all sorts of analyses of the code, including procedures that at least used to be called use-definition and definition-use chain analysis.

If you concoct a "programming language" that enables some scripting in an application, then no matter how trivial you think it is, somebody will eventually write a shockingly large program with it.

I don't know of any readily-available parser generators that generate JavaScript parsers. Recursive descent parsers are not too hard to write, but they can get ugly to maintain and they make it a little difficult to extend the syntax (esp. if you're not very experienced crafting the original version).

Comment: Thank you for your answer, The Language is client specific it's specific to their application and is used to calculate cost based on the information the clients users provide. 
There is no way it can get more complex because the use case is limited it doesn't feed into any other part of the software it's just there to make it as simple and flexible as possible for the client to add / edit costs based on the users decisions on a constructed form

Comment: @James, you of course know more about your application than I do, but I look back on a long history of my own rationalizations about there being "no way" my own designs could get more complicated, and how they **always** end up doing so, especially those that are actually useful to people.

Comment: In any case, if the language is *at all* interesting (and from your examples, it doesn't look so simple to me - anything with an expression grammar has got all sorts of interesting complexity) then the **only** way to reliably interpret and analyze it is with a real parser. That's why parsing is an interesting field of study in computing: it's **the** way to do things like this.

Comment: Second paragraph is gold. *If you concoct a "programming language" that enables some scripting in an application, then no matter how trivial you think it is, somebody will eventually write a shockingly large program with it.* Words to code by.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to look at [JS/CC](http://jscc.jmksf.com/) which is a parser generator that generates a parser for a grammer, in Javascript. You will need to figure out how to describe your language using a BNF and EBNF. Also, JS/CC has its own syntax (which is somewhat close to actual BNF/EBNF) for specifying the grammar. Given the grammer, JS/CC will generate a parser for that grammar.

Your other option, as Pointy said, is to write your own lexer and recursive-descent parser from scratch. Once you have a BNF/EBNF, it's not that hard. I recently wrote a parser from an EBNF in Javascript (the grammar was pretty simple so it wasn't that hard to write one YMMV).

To address your comments about it being "client specific". I will also add my own experience here. If you're providing a scripting language and a scripting environment, there is no better route than an actual parser.

Handling special cases through a bunch of if-elses is going to be horribly painful and a maintenance nightmare. When I was a freshman in college, I tried to write my own language. This was before I knew anything about recursive-descent parsers, or just parsers in general. I figured out by myself that code can be broken down into tokens. From there, I wrote an extremely unwieldy parser using a bunch of if-elses, and also splitting the tokens by spaces and other characters (exactly what you described). The end result was terrible.

Once I read about recursive-descent parsers, I wrote a grammar for my language and easily created a parser in a 10th of the time it took me to write my original parser. Seriously, if you want to save yourself a lot of pain, write an **actual** parser. If you go down your current route, you're going to be fixing issues forever. You're going to have to handle cases where people put the space in the wrong place, or perhaps they have one too many (or one too little) spaces. The only other alternative is to provide an extremely rigid structure (i.e, you must have *exactly* x number of spaces following this statement) which is liable to make your scripting environment extremely unattractive. An actual parser will automatically fix all these problems.

Answer (score 1):

Javascript has a function 'eval'.

```
var code = 'alert(1);';
eval(code);
```

It will show alert. You can use 'eval' to execute basic code.

Comment: As per jballs comment this completely misses the question, the language isn't javascript it's a made up language and I need to tell the user when they've made a mistake in the way they've written it and where

Comment: Sorry! I didn't get your problem's key. It's my fault.

Comment: Definetelly don't use eval - eval is evil - see http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2003/11/01/53329.aspx. I question the need for such a capability.